# ASP.NET - How can I only perform this function on certain filetypes?

Tags: asp.net, download, file-extension

Would like to only use this function with specific file extensions (that I define).  How can I do this in ASP.net?

Basically, the following code allows for any file to be able to be downloaded, just by simply pointing the file to this page `.aspx?file={path to file + file}`  What I am wanting to do, is to exit out of this, if the file does not have an extension from an array that needs to be defined.  For example:  Only want the following extensions to be able to be downloaded via the code below:  .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, .gif, .pdf, .doc, .docx

```
<%@ Page language="vb" runat="server" explicit="true" strict="true" %>
<script language="vb" runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
    Dim strRequest As String = Request.QueryString("file")
    If strRequest <> "" Then
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath(strRequest)
        Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
        If file.Exists Then
            Response.Clear()
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString())
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName)
            Response.End
        Else
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.")
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write("Please provide a file to download.")
    End If
End Sub
</script>
```

How can I change this to exclude this function from working on all file extensions, but those listed:  .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, .gif, .pdf, .doc, .docx

I am thinking like something will need to go in this line here:  `If file.Exists Then`  Will need to change to something like:  `If file.Exists AND file.Extension...`

Comment: Why can't you catch it at the request? E.g. `If strRequest <> "" AndAlso strRequest.EndsWith(".jpg") Then`

Comment: Yeah, that would work also... Post up your answer.  Thanks!  But I need multiple `EndsWith` though.  Also, it should block capitalized extensions as well.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - I got it working now, used `EndsWith` and it works for capitalized extensions also.  Thanks a million!

Comment: If you want to you can post up your answer, and I'll mark it as the answer, but in any case I have solved this with your comment!  Didn't know about `EndsWith`, so that helped a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you can catch it at the request. There's a definitely more elegant solution to the multiple comparing, but for the simplicity case this works:

```
Dim strRequest As String = Request.QueryString("file").ToLower

If strRequest <> "" AndAlso (strRequest.EndsWith(".jpg") OrElse strRequest.EndsWith(".jpeg") OrElse strRequest.EndsWith(".png") OrElse strRequest.EndsWith(".gif") OrElse strRequest.EndsWith(".pdf") Or strRequest.EndsWith(".doc") Or strRequest.EndsWith(".docx") Or strRequest.EndsWith(".bmp")) Then
   '....
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, marking this as my answer, but I used this instead:  `If strRequest <> "" AND strRequest.EndsWith(".jpg") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".jpeg") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".png") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".gif") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".pdf") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".doc") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".docx") OR strRequest.EndsWith(".bmp") Then` This seems to work exactly as I intended.  Can I ask why we need `AndAlso` instead of just `AND`?  And if we use `AndAlso`, can I still do all of my `OR` statements here?  Basically, how does `AndAlso` change the if statement instead of using just `AND`?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. About `AndAlso` - it's a short-circuited version of `And`. If you use `And` - VB.NET evaluates *all* parts of condition even after checking first - the rest make no sense. In your case if you use `And` and strRequest is blank - it will still continue to check the extensions even though it is useless. If you use `AndAlso` - it will stop right away. Same difference betwen `Or` and `OrElse`. So keeping that in mind and keeping in mind operator precedence (you need to use parentesses) I will update my answer with a code snippet.